# Yii2 > How to store html output of a _form view into a string variable

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I want to store the rendered html output of a form view which uses ActiveForm and Html Helper into a variable within my Controller.

I've tried storing result of a renderPartial directly to a variable, which did not work:

```
$htmlform = Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('_form', ['model' => $model]);
```

I've also tried using output buffering to echo the output into a variable, but I could not store the output:

```
ob_start();
echo Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('_form', ['model' => $model]);
$htmlform = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

**View File: _form.php**

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model frontend\models\Epic */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="epic-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'closed')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'organizationid')->textInput() ?>

<div class="form-group">
<?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Create') :    Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

If anyone has an idea on a solution that would be great..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried this way  in a simple ControllerAction and work right  ...in var_dump($test) there the aspected result

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $test =  $this->renderPartial('_form', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
    ]);
    var_dump($test);

}
```